# Maximum value of a for 3 independent real eigen vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the maximum value of a in the below matrix such that it has three linearly independent real eigen vectors.

$  
       M=
      \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
       -3 & 0 & -2 \\
       1 & -1 & 0\\
        0 & a & -2\\
      \end{array} } \right]
    $

---

In the solution, they found the characteristic equation of the matrix and maximized the value of $a$ using the normal procedure of Maxima and minima.

But I don't understand how does this prove that all the three eigen vectors of the matrix with that value of $a$ are linearly independent.

According to me, we need to find 3 distinct eigen values so that the eigen vectors of those eigen values are independent. To get 3 distinct values, rank has to be 3 and the condition should be $|A| \neq 0$. But I am not getting the right answer with this approach.

Can someone tell me why is the first approach working ?

Comment: What do you mean by "maximized the value of $a$"? Maximized with respect to what?

Comment: @rogerl Maximum value of $a$ so that we get three linearly independent vectors .

Comment: where do yo see the "solution"?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Solution is long so I didn't post it. But the answer given is $a=\frac{1}{3√3}$. Can you just tell me the procedure please ? I don't want the exact answer.

Comment: @Moo But how can you tell that the eigen vectors obtained from matrix M with that value of $a$ will be linearly independent?

Comment: @Moo Hmm yeah, after Calculating $a$ and finding the eigen vectors from eigen values seems cumbersome. I had to solve this question in 2 minutes in my test. So I suspected a shorter way to find out the value of $a$.